# RSA: How to generate private key in java and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, rsa

I would like to generate private key in java, save it as a 64 base encoded string in some file
and then encrypt some phrase in C# using this saved file.
I know to generate keys in java and encode it with 64 base.
My question is how do I use this key in C#?
This is a java code prototype to save private key into text file:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
keyGen.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
writeToFile("privateKey", Base64.encode(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
```

I would like to implement following function in C# but can't find how to create RSAParameters or
RSACryptoServiceProvider from private key

```
 public static string DecryptData(string privateKey64Base, string data64Base)
 {
   // create using privateKey64Base
   // create RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa using RSAParameters above
   // byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(data64Base);
 }
```

Comment: I'm sure that already has been asked... I just can't find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/PvkConvert/) contains advice for your situation, since you are writing out PKCS#8 keys (with keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded())

Using this approach you would use the utility on the Java side to get the private key into the PRIVATEKEYBLOB format in the first place.

Alternatively, you could use BouncyCastle C# which can read the key in (see e.g. Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey - you'd need to Base64 decode first of course).

This previous question has the answer for converting from the resulting BC key object to RSACryptoServiceProvider: [BouncyCastle RSAPrivateKey to .NET RSAPrivateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949727/bouncycastle-rsaprivatekey-to-ms-net-rsaprivatekey-c)

Thirdly, you might want to look at using a keystore, e.g. PKCS#12, which is a more standard (and secure) way for storing private keys.

Comment: Thanks! Could you recommend any reading on keystore? I meet it quite often but I don't understand the concept.

Comment: +1, I couldn't access article for few days because website wasn't available, it would be great if you could paste the code in here or add a reference to more persistent websites such as Github.

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample code for whom asked:

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter keyPair = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String("PKCS#8Key"));
var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair);
var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
```

credit to @peter-dettman

Comment: This answer got no upvotes for the past 5 years but it's actually very useful and saved my day.